# How to find minimum value in aggregate $group

Tags: mongodb

I have below collection structure and I want to find minimum score for each student.

```
>db.students.findOne()
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "name" : "aimee Zank",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 1.463179736705023
        },
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 11.78273309957772
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 6.676176060654615
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 35.8740349954354
        }
    ]
}
```

I use below aggregate command

```
db.students.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {_id: "$_id" , min: {$min: '$scores.score'}}
  }
])
```

below is the output:

```
{ "_id" : 199, "min" : [ 82.11742562118049, 49.61295450928224, 28.86823689842918, 5.861613903793295 ] }
{ "_id" : 198, "min" : [ 11.9075674046519, 20.51879961777022, 55.85952928204192, 64.85650354990375 ] }
{ "_id" : 95, "min" : [ 8.58858127638702, 88.40377630359677, 25.71387474240768, 23.73786528217532 ] }
{ "_id" : 11, "min" : [ 78.42617835651868, 82.58372817930675, 87.49924733328717, 15.81264595052612 ] }
{ "_id" : 94, "min" : [ 6.867644836612586, 63.4908039680606, 85.41865347441522, 26.82623527074511 ] }
```

it returns all scores for each student instead of the minimum one. What wrong with my query command? I am using mongo 3.4.

Comment: You are doing the MongoDB University course M101 for which ever language Specific question being *"Find the lowest score and remove it.."* ( paraphrasing, but that's the gist ). The idea of this being a question in the course material is that you work it out yourself as opposed to farming out to StackOverflow for answers. Also defeats the purpose for anyone to answer if you can just look it up. Don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I found that the solution is to add $unwind on `scores.score`. The complete command is:

```
stus = db.students.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$scores"
  },
  {
    $group: {_id: "$_id" , minScore: {$min: '$scores.score'}}
  }
])
```